# Can't produce corrected animated cholorpleth map in JupyterLab

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab

I am trying to produce an animated choloropleth map to detail the spread of the coronavirus through a csv file in JuypterLab. I got the map to output, but not only are the dates wrong, but the map does not animate and is a static image. I tried changing the renderer and some of the values, like in this line of code, but it still does not produce the correct result.

```
df_countrydate = df_countrydate.groupby(['Country','Date']).sum().reset_index()
```

I also tried changed the Ascended value to True, but it still does not produce the correct result

```
import numpy as np 
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

def main():
    graph()
    
def graph():
    
    file = "covid_19_data.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = df.rename(columns={'Country/Region': 'Country'})
    df = df.rename(columns={'ObservationDate': 'Date'})
    pio.renderers.default = "svg"

    df_countries = df.groupby(['Country', 'Date']).sum().reset_index().sort_values('Date', ascending=False)
    df_countries = df_countries.drop_duplicates(subset=['Country'])
    df_countries = df_countries[df_countries['Confirmed'] > 0]
    df_countrydate = df[df['Confirmed']>0]
    df_countrydate = df_countrydate.groupby(['Date','Country']).sum().reset_index()
    df_countrydate


    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
       locations=df_countries['Country'],
       locationmode='country names',
       z=df_countries['Confirmed'],
       colorscale='Inferno',

    ))
    
    fig = px.choropleth(df_countrydate, 
                    locations="Country", 
                    locationmode = "country names",
                    color="Confirmed", 
                    hover_name="Country", 
                    animation_frame="Date"
                   )
    fig.update_layout(
    title_text = 'Global Spread of Coronavirus',
    title_x = 0.5,
    geo=dict(
        showframe = False,
        showcoastlines = False,
    ))
    

    fig.show()


main()
```

Incorrect Graph Output [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choropleth map can be specified only with px.choropleth(). The data was obtained from [here](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-vaccinations) and recalculated to create data in years. This is because animation in days is very slow. Also, the slider is a numeric string, so I converted it to a string and sorted it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

row_data = pd.read_csv('./data/owid-covid-data.csv', sep=',')
df = row_data.loc[:,['iso_code','continent','location','date','total_cases']]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['iso_code','continent','location']).resample('1M')['total_cases'].sum().reset_index()

df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
df.sort_values('date', ascending=True, inplace=True)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,               
              locations="iso_code",               
              color="total_cases",
              hover_name="location",  
              animation_frame="date",    
              color_continuous_scale='Plasma',  
              height=600             
)

fig.update_layout(
title_text = 'Global Spread of Coronavirus',
title_x = 0.5,
geo=dict(
    showframe = False,
    showcoastlines = False,
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer. Click on the check mark under the lower triangle.

Comment: What renderer should I use so that it animated in jupyter?

Comment: Ignore my above comment, I changed the renderer to colab and now it works great. Thank you for the help!